# Knockout computed write not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, knockout.js

I have a simple grid, with checkable rows.

Each row represents basically this object:

```
function Person(name, isChecked, isDisabled) {
        this.name = name;
        this.isChecked = ko.observable(isChecked);
        this.isDisabled = ko.observable(isDisabled);
    };
```

There's also a **check all** checkbox in the grid header, which should check all the **non-disabled** rows or un-check them (depending on the state). This should also work the other way around, meaning that when I check all the rows within the grid (clickin on each row's checkbox), the header checkbox should be checked.

The problem is, the computed bound to the **check all** checkbox fails to execute.

See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/eww5dn8q/.

Notice that when you check them all, the alert within the `write` function is executed. However, when you uncheck, it no longer works.

Consider this version where I comment the `if` statement (lines 30 and 32): http://jsfiddle.net/qws3f7js/.

In this version, it seems to run well whether it's check or uncheck, but at the cost of not taking into account the `disabled` rows.

I'm pretty sure there's a minor thing I'm missing there..

Comment: It's indeed something 'minor': remove the `return false;` statement from your `$.each` loop in the computed's  `read` function and all works (except the CheckAll is checked as soon as 1 item is). For it to work as expected, I slightly modified your `read` function in the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kevinvanlierde/eww5dn8q/1/

Comment: Seems to be what I need. Maybe move your comment in an answer so I can accept it? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cf. comment on question:
The 'error' was indeed minor. Slightly modifying the computed's `read` function did the trick (plus it simplifies the `if else` clause to an `if`):

```
  read: function () {
      var isAllSelected = true;
      $.each(self.myData(), function(i, person){
          if(!person.isChecked() && !person.isDisabled()){
              isAllSelected = false;
          }
      });
      return isAllSelected;
  },
```

See fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/kevinvanlierde/eww5dn8q/1/